# Where are Redmine default priority names stored

Tags: redmine

I have a read-only access to our Redmine DB (MySQL). This rights were given to me so I could build some reports.

And now I am facing a problem.

I got an `issues` table and there is a field named `priority_id`. How can I get priority names (like `Normal`,`Urgent` etc that represent each `id`)?

I searched DB/SO/google but couldn't found where this values are stored, only Priority Plug-in for Redmine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redmine stores the defined priorities as well as other similar data (like time entry activities or document categories) in a database table called `enumerations`. The defined enumerations can be shown with this example SQL:

```
SELECT name FROM enumerations WHERE type = 'IssuePriority' ORDER BY position ASC;
```

To associate the priority to issues, you can e.g. use

```
SELECT issues.id, issues.subject, enumerations.name FROM issues LEFT OUTER JOIN enumerations ON issues.priority_id = enumerations.id AND enumerations.type = 'IssuePriority'
```

On the Redmine web interface, you can edit the data in *Administration* -> *Enumerations*.